Queries work in Postgres but in Postman and Express they return empty array
I am working on a project that fetches data from a PostgreSQL database, using pg and express.js for the backend connectivity. The API endpoint that I have written below doesn't return any data. Same goes for on Postman. It doesn't even log the data from result.rows on the console
//get particular event
app.get("/api/v1/events/:id", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await db.query("select name, date, time, venue, title, about from event e join club c on e.club_id=c.club_id where event_id = $1;", [req.params.id]);
        console.log(result.rows);
        res.json(result.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

Furthermore, Postman tries to fetch data even when I comment out the code for the endpoint above but says it can't get data from another endpoint which actually exists.
When I run the same query on postgres, it returns data. A few other endpoints work, like this one
// get upcoming/ongoing/completed events
app.get("/api/v1/events/:status", async (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.params.status)
    try {
        const result = await db.query("select event_id, name, date, time, venue, title from event e join club c on e.club_id=c.club_id where status = $1;", [req.params.status]);
        //console.log(result.rows);
        res.status(200).json(result.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});

Please help me and give your opinion on how to solve this problem. It's for a project that I need to submit in 2 days (17-05-2024). Thanks a lot!!

Can you share me the exact error you got during postman testing??

Express will match app.get("/api/v1/events/:id" and app.get("/api/v1/events/:status" as the same route since /api/v1/events/ is shared by both and only differentiated by the query param. Either change your routes to differentiate them or use req.query like in this blog.

@jQueeny yes that was the main problem. It's fixed now. Thanks a lot!!
